# Ajax Call not working with asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server, ajax

Ajax Call not working. When I click on btnsubmit, it first shows alert hi and then "Record Save to Database" but data not saving to database. The stored procedure name is "Ajax".

How to solve the error? Thanks in advance..

Procedure is:

```
create procedure Ajax
    @EmpID nvarchar(50),
    @EmpName nvarchar(50),
    @EmpAddress nvarchar(50)
as
begin
    insert into NewEmp (EmpID, EmpName, EmpAddress) 
    values (@EmpID, @EmpName, @EmpAddress)
end
```

HTMl Page:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
   $("#btnsubmit").click(function () {
    var EmpID = $('#TxtID').val();
    var EmpName = $('#TxtName').val();
    var EmpAddress = $('#TxtAdd').val();
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     url: "Default11.aspx/InserData",
     data: "{'EmpID':'" +EmpID + "','EmpName':'" + EmpName + "','EmpAddress':'" + EmpAddress + "'}",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (response) {
       alert("Hi");                     
       $("#TxtID").val(''); $("#TxtName").val(''); $("#TxtAdd").val('');
       alert("Record Save to Databse");           
      },
      error: function () {
       alert("Error");
      }
     });
    });
   });
  </script>
 <div>

<asp:TextBox ID="TxtID" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
 <br />
 EmpName:-<asp:TextBox ID="TxtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <br />
 Addresss:-<asp:TextBox ID="TxtAdd" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <br />
 <input type="button" id="btnsubmit" value="Submit" />  
 </div>
```

C# Code:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Services;

public partial class Default11 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static bool InserData(string EmpID, string EmpName, string EmpAddress)
    {
        SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AjaxInsert"].ConnectionString);
        try {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Ajax",scon);
            scon.Open();
            cmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "Ajax";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", EmpID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", EmpName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpAddress", EmpAddress);

            cmd.Connection = scon;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            scon.Close();

            // return "success";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
           // return"error";
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: check `data` param format. You can remove the single quotes from the `keys`

Comment: Have you debug the code of c# file? Is you passing the correct values to procedure ?

Comment: remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` from your script and try then.. Hopefully it will work

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked via breakpoints the string the following command.

```
 "{'EmpID':'" +EmpID + "','EmpName':'" + EmpName + "','EmpAddress':'" + EmpAddress + "'}"
```

returns to server?

Why not `data: { EmpID: EmpID , EmpName: EmpName , EmpAddress: EmpAddress }` ?

Answer (score 0):

you cant use asp controls in java scritpt .becase asp controls can be accessable at out side i.e server side only .insted of server contols use html controls like below 
        EmpID:-
        
        EmpName:-
        
        Addresss:-

Answer (score 0):

You are use `asp control` for get input values from user. so make changes in jQuery code as given below. because i was also face same problems. So i hope it would help to you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#btnsubmit").click(function () {
    var EmpID = $('#<%=TxtID.ClientID%>').val();
    var EmpName = $('#<%=TxtName.ClientID%>').val();
    var EmpAddress = $('#<%=TxtAdd.ClientID%>').val();
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     url: "Default11.aspx/InserData",
     data: "{'EmpID':'" +EmpID + "','EmpName':'" + EmpName + "','EmpAddress':'" + EmpAddress + "'}",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (response) {
       alert("Hi");                     
       $('#<%=TxtID.ClientID%>').val('');
       $('#<%=TxtName.ClientID%>').val('');
       $('#<%=TxtAdd.ClientID%>').val('');
       alert("Record Save to Database");           
      },
      error: function () {
       alert("Error");
      }
     });
    });
   });
  </script>
```

Comment: please check what is in data while you call web method